# How to add a authorization header to a user request and the proxy it to another server api with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, authorization

You see this is what happen, the client side has a cookie with http only flag and inside of it a **JWT** that will be use by the **API server** to authorize the request , the thing is that the **JWT** should be in a **Authorization header** so I am using a middle server to catch the client request, extract the **JWT** from the cookie, set the **Authorization Header** within client request and then forward the request to the API server to fetch the data.

The main problem is that I dont know how properly set the header from the **middle server** or even if that is posible, because every time I try to forward to the **API server** this last got the **Authorization header** undefined that I supposedly set in the **middleware server**.

So, how can I set a **Authorization Header** and forward to another server properly?, the **middle server** and the **API server** both uses **NodeJS and Express**.

This is so far the code from the **middle server** I have (dont worry about the cookie extraction part, this is just testing propuses):

```
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8083;

app.use(cors());
// app.use(express.json());

app.use('/graphql',
(req, res, next) => {
    req.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZFVzZXIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkphY2sifQ.5y3IhB4i_THfKZr5BYe6dZruhOUbQt7SRT_rrssApCo`;
    next()
},
proxy('http://localhost:8081/graphql'));

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`http://localhost:${PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

After a while looking for another answers and reading the documentation [documentation](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy#proxyreqoptdecorator--supports-promise-form) I found that the package **express-http-proxy** has the exactly the property I needed, that is **proxyReqOptDecorator**. When you declare the proxy middleware the second arguament is a object whit diferent options like propertiess, the **proxyReqOptDecorator** recive a function with 2 parameters: **proxyReqOpts** to atach any property to the request object and **the original request object** (as far as I did understand).

So, **in order to solve the problem** and set the **Authorization header** to the request object before forawrd I did change the code adding the property **proxyReqOptDecorator**:

```
app.post('/graphql',
proxy('http://localhost:8081/graphql',{
    proxyReqOptDecorator: function(proxyReqOpts, srcReq) {
        proxyReqOpts.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZFVzZXIiOiI2MDNjYzM0ZTM2ZTk0MjI0MTNkYzNmZDUiLCJuYW1lIjoiRGFuaWVsIn0._ZJytuJJoG8RM6kki6YZcMlYAh7M0zAZWE54x7i3nhs`;
        return proxyReqOpts;
      }
}));
```

Well thats it, thats solved the problem. I still don't know why the first code didn't work and if there are any other ways to do this but I expect that work for you too.